# What's up with these Screw Attack looking things on my map?

Tags: doom-2016

These icons crop up from time to time.

[image]

At first I thought they showed north, but there are maps with several of them. Then I thought maybe they were teleporters, but that doesn't seem to line up either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the symbol for power-ups, such as Quad Damage, Invulnerability, Haste, etc. They all seem to share the same map icon.

Comment: To complete the list, add Berserk and MegaHealth and you have all types of bonuses.